# Second Bootstrap model opens automatically after first model close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Here is the code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '#saves', function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
       $("#exampleModal").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
           $('#Newmodel').modal('show')
       });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Modal</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch demo modal
        </button>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" id="saves" class="btn btn-primary">New Model</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="Newmodel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have same code as link code except there is also ajax request and jquery in the success function. In the first model, if I submit, then it triggers ajax request and in the success function, as per jquery code, close first modal and open second modal with message. In the first time when second modal opens there is no issue.

The problem is that second time when I open first modal and after that if I do not want ajax request like click submit, sending data and close existing modal and open new modal. So I click close button or any outer area of page. so the second modal should not open because no trigger for second modal. but it still close first modal and open second Modal.

I don't know why this is happening on after first run. I do not want to open second modal except submit click. I also tried without "hidden.bs.modal()" function but in that method scrollbar works on background page other than modal.
How can I do that without background scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be that this keeps getting triggered

`$("#exampleModal").on("hidden.bs.modal",function() {`

I'm curious if there's a way to chain events. Like if you have an onclick and the `hidden.bs.modal` event, do something. Is that what you're looking to do?  The way you have it will always run the code in that condition despite it being within the other event condition.

The following works the way you want it:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '#saves', function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
       $('#Newmodel').modal('show');
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Modal</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch demo modal
        </button>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" id="saves" class="btn btn-primary">New Model</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="Newmodel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also tried it. It works fine. In this code scrolling works for background page and I don't want this. Is there any other method?

Comment: You mean scrolling is enabled when you're viewing it on that little window after you click on **Run code snippet**? If so, that can be turned off with `.modal-open .modal { overflow: hidden; }`. But, if you fill your modal with lots of information that goes beyond the window size, people won't be able to scroll to it. If you click on the **Full page** link in the top right of the snippet area you'll see it on the full page. No scrolling is happening there.